# The minimum number of digits after the floating-point, which uniquely identify every irrational square root

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, irrational-numbers

**Let the following:**

- $B:$ a natural number larger than $1$
- $S:$ a set of irrational numbers in the range $(0,1)$ represented in base $B$
- $L:$ the minimal prefix length which uniquely identifies every element in $S$

---

With $S=\{r|r=\sqrt[2]{n}-\lfloor\sqrt[2]{n}\rfloor,r\neq0,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, is it possible to express $L$ as a function of $B$?

An answer for specific bases (binary and decimal in particular) would also be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt {n+1}-\sqrt n = \cfrac 1{\sqrt {n+1}+\sqrt n}$ and can therefore be made arbitrarily small so that however many digits $L$ you choose, you can find square roots so close together that $L$ digits will not distinguish them.

Comment: So in simple words, the larger a number becomes, the less it is distinguishable by the fractional part of its square root?

Comment: @barakmanos Indeed so - sorry.

Comment: OK, that's fairly simple (I actually feel kinda dumb not realizing it in the first place)... Thanks a lot :)